# SOAP service using Spring. Escaping special characters

Tags: java, soap, soapui, spring-ws

I have a SOAP web service developed using Spring framework. Whenever the request contains some invalid data i need to display error message like below

```
Error occurred. Invalid data for <Field Name>.
```

So my code looks as below for name validation. This error will be sent as response wheneve no value passed for the name field.

```
Assert.notNull(name, "Error occurred. No value passed for the field <name>. ");
```

So what i expected as out out is

```
Error occurred. No value passed for the field <name>.
```

But the response in SOAP UI was like below.

```
Error occurred. No value passed for the field &lt;name>.
```

How to display the proper < symbol in SOAP UI? I tried CDATA. But not sure how the receiver process the request with CDATA.

With CDATA message in SOAP UI was like below

```
Error occurred. No value passed for the field <![CDATA[<]]name>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML Specification states:

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " &amp; " and " &lt; " respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string " &gt; ", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either " &gt; " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

So, you need to either escape the left angle bracket in your error string:

```
Error occurred. No value passed for the field &lt;name>.
```

Or encapsulate the entire error string in a CDATA section:

```
<![CDATA[Error occurred. No value passed for the field <name>.]]>
```

For more information see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax

Comment: If my message is "<![CDATA[Error occurred. No value passed for the field <name>.]]>" then will it be processed properly by the receiver/client?

Comment: Moreover escaping means what? I tried some thing like "Assert.notNull(name, "Error occurred. No value passed for the field &amp;name>. ");" but still I am not getting what I want.